# Candlestick Graph is not correctly shaped

Tags: python, candlestick-chart

I try to graph candlestick chart with `candlestick_ohlc` method from `mplfinance` module. I have a DataFrame indexed with Date data in `datetime` type and prices in OHLC order.

My code for matplotlib:

```
from mplfinance.original_flavor import candlestick_ohlc

# creating Subplots
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
 
# plotting the data
candlestick_ohlc(ax, df.values, width = 0.6,
                 colorup = 'green', colordown = 'red',
                 alpha = 0.8)

plt.show()
```

I have unexpected result for my graph.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRh2g.png)

- I thought that candlesticks on my graph were showing also Date in timestamps and this was why I had misshaped thickness in the graph, but it wasn't.
- I tried to adjust several parameters and ended up with the most simple code and the resulting graph was the same.
- I went through all of the questions of stackoverflow, my problem persists.

Why can't I have correct Candlestick Charts?

Comment: Check the candlestick_ohlc documenation, "time must be in float date format - see date2num", and the width is the "fraction of a day for the rectangle width". So either you need to convert your dates, or you have to many values per day (if you're plotting a value every second, and each candle is 0.6 day long, it will not look nice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment is correct that, for `candlestick_ohlc()`, the `"time must be in float date format - see date2num"`.

That said, `candlestick_ohlc()` is *obsolete and no longer supported*.  It requires that you convert your datetimes to matplotlib float date format, and that you format the x-axis dates yourself.

I strongly recommend you use the new version of [**`mplfinance`**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance#basic-usage) which does all that for you, into which you can simply pass a dataframe with a datetime index. [**See documentation here**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance#basic-usage).

You code can then simply be:

```py
import mplfinance as mpf

# plotting the data
mpf.plot(df, style='yahoo')
```

[For further documentation (how to customize plots, colors, etc) click here](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance#contents-and-tutorials).